# check if string contains another column value

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, contains

I have a dataframe and would like to check if a column value contains another column value.

```
    name1   name2
0   aa      aab
1   xyz     x
```

the below doesn't work

```
df = df.assign(name1_contains_name2=df.name1.str.contains(df.name2),
            name2_contains_name1=df.name2.str.contains(df.name1))
```

but I would like to get the below dataframe

```
    name1   name2   name1_contains_name2    name2_contains_name1
0   aa      aab     False                   True
1   xyz     x       True                    False
```

How can I write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need test per rows use list comprehensions:

```
z = list(zip(df.name1, df.name2))
out = df.assign(name1_contains_name2=[b in a for a, b in z],
               name2_contains_name1=[a in b for a, b in z])
print (out)
  name1 name2  name1_contains_name2  name2_contains_name1
0    aa   aab                 False                  True
1   xyz     x                  True                 False
```

Or use one list comprehension with DataFrame constructor:

```
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame([[(b in a), (a in b)] for a, b in zip(df.name1, df.name2)], 
                  columns=['name1_contains_name','name2_contains_name1'],
                  index=df.index))

print (out)
  name1 name2  name1_contains_name  name2_contains_name1
0    aa   aab                False                  True
1   xyz     x                 True                 False
```

If need test per all values use `|` with join for regex `OR`:

```
out = df.assign(name1_contains_name2=df.name1.str.contains('|'.join(df.name2)),
                name2_contains_name1=df.name2.str.contains('|'.join(df.name1)))
print (out)

  name1 name2  name1_contains_name2  name2_contains_name1
0    aa   aab                 False                  True
1   xyz     x                  True                 False
```

---

Difference is possible seen in added new line to DataFrame:

```
print (df)
  name1 name2
0    aa   aab
1   xyz     x
2     b  xyza

out = df.assign(name1_contains_name2=df.name1.str.contains('|'.join(df.name2)),
                name2_contains_name1=df.name2.str.contains('|'.join(df.name1)))
print (out)
  name1 name2  name1_contains_name2  name2_contains_name1
0    aa   aab                 False                  True
1   xyz     x                  True                 False
2     b  xyza                 False                  True

z = list(zip(df.name1, df.name2))
out1 = df.assign(name1_contains_name2=[b in a for a, b in z],
               name2_contains_name1=[a in b for a, b in z])
print (out1)
  name1 name2  name1_contains_name2  name2_contains_name1
0    aa   aab                 False                  True
1   xyz     x                  True                 False
2     b  xyza                 False                 False
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible option (*that can handle more than two columns*) using [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and [membership operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) with [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) :

```
from itertools import permutations

names = ["name1", "name2"] # << add more if needed

checks = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [(n2 in n1) for n1, n2 in permutations(vals, 2)]
        for vals in df[names].to_numpy()
    ],
    columns=map("{0[0]}_contains_{0[1]}".format, permutations(names, 2)),
)

out = df.join(checks)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  name1 name2  name1_contains_name2  name2_contains_name1
0    aa   aab                 False                  True
1   xyz     x                  True                 False
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by iterating through the rows and checking the values of the names

```
Name1InName2 = list()
Name2InName1 = list()    
for row in df.iterrows():
        Name1InName2.append(row[1].values[0] in row[1].values[1])
        Name2InName1.append(row[1].values[1] in row[1].values[0])
```

After that, assign the lists to the pandas df

```
df["name1_contains_name2"] = Name2InName1
df["name2_contains_name1"] = Name1InName2
```